# Java SWING: adding a JTextField (never used anywhere) randomly makes the screen go white

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, visibility

I'm developing on ubuntu 10.04 with using Eclipse, and when I add a `JTextField` into the following code (that I don't use anywhere, or make visible!) the window, instead of displaying the images like it's supposed to, goes blank.

Anyone have any idea what's causing this?

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Testi {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ImageIcon icon1 = new ImageIcon("background.jpg");
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(700,500);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setSize(600, 600);
    panel.setOpaque(false);

    frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));

    JLabel label = new JLabel();
    label.setSize(500, 500);
    label.setIcon(icon1);
    label.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));


        // FOLLOWING LINE IS THE PROBLEM: when in code, the screen goes white
    JTextArea text1 = new JTextArea("asd");

    label.add(panel);
    frame.add(label);       
}
}
```

Comment: I'm no expert on Java frames, but I've never seen an entire GUI being displayed from inside a JLabel before. Is that normal?

Comment: @thasc Nope, not what JLabel should be used for. It is possible tsiki just did that to exemplify the issue.

Comment: You've got a very strange GUI.

Comment: Can you create a smaller example? There is a lot of junk here.  Removing it might identify the problem, or at least remove a lost of waste.

Comment: Yes, it was the only way I could figure out how to make the cards lay on top of the background image. I'm open to better suggestions if anyone has any, though.

Comment: @jzd done, cut stuff out that didn't affect the problem

Comment: @tsiki, screen is blank whether the text field line exists or not when I run your latest version.

Comment: @jzd I don't know what to say, for me it simply displays the background image when I run it without the JTextArea line, and most of the time goes blank when I run it with it.

Comment: @tsiki, sorry, I didn't have a background image in place.  I see it either way.

Comment: Tried it as well, but the frame contents were always blank for me. Perhaps it couldn't find the image. At any rate, if it works for jzd then maybe it's a bug in the AWT implementation for the graphics toolkit Ubuntu uses (not sure which one it is).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works for me, which makes me think it is a EDT issue.  Move your call to `setVisible` to the end of your main method.

From this link: http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/threads/threads1.html

*This method is thread safe, although most Swing methods are not.
 An application's GUI can often be constructed and shown in the main thread: The following typical code is safe, as long as no components (Swing or otherwise) have been realized:*

```
public class MyApplication {
public static void main(String[] args) {
   JFrame f = new JFrame("Labels");
   // Add components to 
   // the frame here... 
   f.pack(); 
   f.show(); 
   // Don't do any more GUI work here... 
   } 
}
```

*All the code shown above runs on the "main" thread. The f.pack() call realizes the components under the JFrame. This means that, technically, the f.show() call is unsafe  and should be executed in the event-dispatching thread. However, as  long as the program doesn't already have a visible GUI, it's exceedingly  unlikely that the JFrame or its contents will receive a paint() call before f.show() returns. Because  there's no GUI code after the f.show() call, all GUI  work moves from the main thread to the event-dispatching thread, and  the preceding code is, in practice, thread-safe.*

Comment: Thank you, this was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
For me the fix was to move the call to `frame.setVisible()` below the part where I added my components.