# Adding a JTextFIeld to a Panel make whole frame goes white

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

So I got that login class in Java, you can find it on the end.
When I try to add a JTextField, for username and password Input, the whole screen goes white, like its rendering somewhere. I cant see what I am doing wrong.

Im trying to program the UI in code, using IntelliJ.

I do not want to use NetBeans or Eclipse GUI Tools, because I feel it will be better to me learn how do the thing directly in code.

The JTextField Class that I created can be found down there, in the end of code.

In a whole scenario, I am doing this righit?

Thats is how I build interface classes in Java?

It's dificult to find good material on web, and I am trying to apply the things in know in programing in other langagues in java...

That class will be added to a main Frame in main class, that class will be the only one Frame, the other class all will be panels.

Thank you guys for reading, there is the code:

```java
package com.GUI;
import com.components.JButtons;
import com.components.JLabels;
import com.components.JPanels;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
//import javax.swing.JPanel;
//import javax.swing.JTextField;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
//import java.awt.Color;
//import java.awt.Dimension;


public class Login2 extends JPanel {

    JButtons Entrar = new JButtons(125, 25, "ENTRAR");
    JButtons Cadastrar = new JButtons(125, 25, "CADASTRAR");
    JButtons Sair = new JButtons(125, 25, "SAIR");

    public Login2() {
        this.setBounds(0, 0, 250, 540);
        this.setLayout(null);
        this.add(Container());
    }

    private JPanels Container() {
        JPanels Container = new JPanels(0, 0, 250, 540);
        Container.setLayout(null);
        Container.setBackground(Color.blue);
        Container.add(Logo());
        Container.add(Formulario());
        Container.add(ButtonsPanel());
        return Container;
    }

    private JPanels Logo(){
        JPanels Logo = new JPanels(75,30,100,100);
        Logo.setBackground(Color.red);

        return Logo;
    }

    private JPanels Formulario(){
        JPanels Formulario = new JPanels(25, 150, 200, 160);
        Formulario.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        Formulario.setLayout(null);
        Formulario.add(FSCPanel());
        Formulario.add(UsuarioPanel());
        Formulario.add(UsuarioFieldPanel());
        Formulario.add(SenhaPanel());
        Formulario.add(SenhaFieldPanel());
        return Formulario;
    }

    private JPanels FSCPanel(){
        JPanels FSC = new JPanels(25, 5, 150, 30);
        FSC.add(new JLabels("Faça seu LogIn!", 20, 1));
        return FSC;
    }

    private JPanels ButtonsPanel(){
        JPanels ButtonsLabel = new JPanels(50, 320, 150, 130);
        ButtonsLabel.setLayout(null);
        ButtonsLabel.add(EPanel());
        ButtonsLabel.add(CPanel());
        ButtonsLabel.add(SPanel());
        return ButtonsLabel;
    }

    private JPanels EPanel(){
        JPanels EPanel = new JPanels(10, 5, 125, 30);
        EPanel.add(Entrar);
        return EPanel;
    }

    private JPanels CPanel(){
        JPanels CPanel = new JPanels(10, 40, 125, 30);
        CPanel.add(Cadastrar);
        return CPanel;
    }

    private JPanels SPanel(){
        JPanels SPanel = new JPanels(10, 75, 125, 30);
        SPanel.add(Sair);
        return SPanel;
    }

    private JPanels UsuarioPanel(){
        JPanels UsuarioPanel = new JPanels(10, 40, 50, 20);
        UsuarioPanel.add(new JLabels("Usuario:", 12, 1));
        return UsuarioPanel;
    }

    private JPanels UsuarioFieldPanel(){
        JPanels UsuarioFieldPanel = new JPanels(10, 63, 150, 30);
        UsuarioFieldPanel.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        UsuarioFieldPanel.setLayout(null);
        //UsuarioFieldPanel.add(UsuarioField());
        return UsuarioFieldPanel;
    }

    private JTextField UsuarioField(){
        JTextField UsuarioField = new JTextField();
        UsuarioField.setBounds(0, 0, 20, 10);
        UsuarioField.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(20, 10));
        UsuarioField.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(20, 10));
        return UsuarioField;
    }

    private JPanels SenhaPanel(){
        JPanels Senha = new JPanels(10, 100, 50, 20);
        Senha.add(new JLabels("Senha:", 12, 1));
        return Senha;
    }

    private JPanels SenhaFieldPanel(){
        JPanels SenhaFieldPanel = new JPanels(10, 125, 150, 30);
        SenhaFieldPanel.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        SenhaFieldPanel.setLayout(null);
        //SenhaFieldPanel.add(SenhaField());
        return SenhaFieldPanel;
    }

    private JTextField SenhaField(){
        JTextField SenhaField = new JTextField();
        SenhaField.setBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);
        SenhaField.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(0, 0));
        SenhaField.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(0, 0));
        return SenhaField;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure about this but why do you set the bounds to all zeros, as well as the dimensions for the size are all zeros?

Comment: @MarcusSlover you mean from every component or the ones about JTextfield?
Even with no dimensons, the screen goes white, any kind of JTextField at that class makes screen go white...

Comment: 1) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556). 2) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently.

Comment: .. 3) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 4) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height - to show how the extra space should be used. 5)  *"But thats open me to other question:"* Each SO Q&A should focus on exactly ***one*** question. That way it's easier for others to find later.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution at:

[Java SWING: adding a JTextField (never used anywhere) randomly makes the screen go white](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5720224/java-swing-adding-a-jtextfield-never-used-anywhere-randomly-makes-the-screen)

looks like making the main frame be set visible after adding it components make the JTextFields appear.

But thats open me to other question:

That will be not the only frame of my program, after users login, it will be a DashBoard class, and I can only add it if user its logged.

And, can I make the buttom of Login returns like a bool if its true?

My main frama only adds 'login', so how could I do that?

Should I open other stack?